# Exporting Orders with Full Details

Tags: orders, customer, magento-2.0, export

I want to export all the orders till date (without using extension) with Following Details
- Name
- E-mail
- Phone

Can someone guide me on DB query to export the same? Default export in panel only allows name and email, no phone numbers.

Comment: which Magento version you are using? Name of the customer?, Phone of what (billing/shipping address) ?

Comment: 2.0.19. Billing Details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query to have what you need

> SELECT T0.entity_id As OrderId,CONCAT_WS(' ',T0.customer_firstname
>   ,T0.customer_lastname) AS Name,T0.customer_email As Email,
>   T1.telephone As Telephone from sales_order T0 inner join
>   sales_order_address T1 on T1.parent_id = T0.entity_id where
>   T1.address_type ="billing"